# What statistical analysis to use for a particular research question?

Tags: psychology

I am having trouble with figuring out which statistical analysis would be appropriate for a study that I am currently running. What I want to be able to compare is profiles of scores from a measure at two different time points.

I.e. I have data from T1 and T3 of a measure that has 19 scales. I want to be able to test if there is a significant difference between the two profiles... But I do not have two groups for my IV (i guess I could) but I am still struggling with this analysis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two time points of the same individuals with one measure? Can you explain "a measure that has 19 scales"? One  variable or several?

Comment: yes so basically I have a personality measure that has 19 scales on it... so I want to compare the whole profile of the measure. But I have data from two different time point on the same measure.

Comment: Are you sure there are 19 _scales_, and not 19 _items_ (i.e., questions) which measure some <19 personality traits?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a group of individuals tested at two time point on (an aggregated) independent variable. Such research designs are testing for significant changes in a mean independent variable such that: $H_0:\mu_1 =\mu_2$. As you are testing the same individuals at different points, the measures are dependent. If you have only two time points, you can use a **paired *t*-test**. If you have more than two, you can use **repeated measures ANOVA**.